# Using GMAP.NET for c#, how do I use a marker OnMarkerClick without calling map MouseClick?

Tags: c#, winforms, gmap.net

When I click on the map, I want to bring up a menu that includes adding a location.  When I click on a marker I bring up another menu, but it also fires the map MouseClick Event.  Can I convert so MouseClick only fires when I click on the map with out clicking any marker?  Thank you

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I am using Winforms - Visual Studio C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map click is detected first. You can check several properties on the map control to determine if you've clicked "something" on the map.

```
void map_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Marker hit? " + ((GMapControl)sender).IsMouseOverMarker);
     Console.WriteLine("Polygon hit? " + ((GMapControl)sender).IsMouseOverPolygon);
     Console.WriteLine("Route hit? " + ((GMapControl)sender).IsMouseOverRoute);
}
```

If you found a hit, simply don't show the map menu and continue to handle the click in the appropriate click handler of the marker etc.